# SQL to JPQL - haversine formula

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I've got this SQL query which is returning locations from the spot table and ordering them by distance in km.
The query works in SQL, but I'm facing some difficulties converting it to JPQL.
I am using static values for the moment to make it easier to read.

SQL - works

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(60.1733) ) * cos( radians( spot.spot_latitude )) 
        * cos( radians(spot.spot_longitude) - radians(24.941)) + sin(radians(60.1733)) 
        * sin( radians(spot.spot_latitude)))) AS distance 

    FROM spot

    WHERE spot_id = spot_id 
        HAVING distance < 10    
        ORDER BY distance
```

JPQL - Dosen't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT s, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(60.1733) ) * cos( radians( spot.spot_latitude ))
        * cos( radians(spot.spot_longitude) - radians(24.941)) + sin(radians(60.1733))
        * sin( radians(spot.spot_latitude)))) AS distance 

    FROM spot  

    WHERE s.spot_id = s.spot_id
        HAVING distance < 10
        ORDER BY s.distance
```

The JPQL throws two exceptions with root cause:

```
    A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException: 
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: skatebayBackend
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@2f2c9b19

Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [skatebay_pu] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Spot.getSpotsInMyArea] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on rest.SpotApi
```

Comment: JPQL doesnt have many of those functions available (acos, cos, radians, sin etc). JPQL != SQL. Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus) do allow them, see http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_functions_arithmetic . No idea about EclipseLink. Use of Geospatial java types would clearly make that much easier

Comment: @BillyFrost that's what i was afraid of, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: Eclipselink docs seem to be this http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions  which does not allow them as you wrote them. Likely you'd have to use `FUNCTION` or `FUNC` around them; not pretty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL works with entities and not with database tables. You have at least two options here:

Make sure that you have entity mapped to table and use correct syntax for your query. However JPQL provides less possibilities than SQL. 
 So maybe in your case it would be easier to create native query and then you can use normal sql.

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select * from table...");
List<Object> string = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: That's what I've found out too, it works with NativeQuery. Extra question is, is there a way to make it as an annotation, like @NamedQueries. Would like to have all my query's in the entity class it self

Comment: You can use annotation @NamedNativeQuery(name = "queryName", query = "sql") for the entity and then call it as named query Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("queryName");

Answer (score 0):

You used an alias `s` in JPQL in the where clause, do this instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(60.1733) ) * cos( radians( spot.spot_latitude ))
        * cos( radians(spot.spot_longitude) - radians(24.941)) + sin(radians(60.1733))
        * sin( radians(spot.spot_latitude)))) AS distance 

    FROM spot AS s

    WHERE s.spot_id = s.spot_id
        HAVING distance < 10
        ORDER BY s.distance
```